# JQ - Flattening keys in array gives cartesian product

Tags: json, jq

I have some json which i'm trying to simplify:

```
{
  "name": "vehicles",
  "details": [
    {
      "type": "passenger",
      "engine": {
        "type": "electric"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "commercial",
      "engine": {
        "type": "diesel"
      }
    }
```

I want engine.type to become engineType.  So I'm trying to add a new field, then delete the old one:

`echo $json|jq '(.details[].engineType = .details[].engine.type)|del(.details[].engine.type)'`

But this is giving me a cartesian product:

```
{
  "name": "vehicles",
  "details": [
    {
      "type": "passenger",
      "engine": {},
      "engineType": "electric"
    },
    {
      "type": "commercial",
      "engine": {},
      "engineType": "electric"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "vehicles",
  "details": [
    {
      "type": "passenger",
      "engine": {},
      "engineType": "diesel"
    },
    {
      "type": "commercial",
      "engine": {},
      "engineType": "diesel"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm sure the fix is simple, but I can't work out the right way to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you use `.details[]`, another iteration is performed (in the context of the previous one). Factor it out, and perform your operations in a subcontext. Here's an example using the [update operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#update-assignment) `|=`:

```bash
.details[] |= (.enginetype = .engine.type | del(.engine.type))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7pCYndyMlSH)

Note: To remove the entire `.engine` field, replace `del(.engine.type)` with `del(.engine)`. Or use a positive approach by defining what (else) to keep (the `.type` field in this case): `.details[] |= {type, enginetype: .engine.type}`.